# unsetting array value based on partial string

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array

```
Array ( 
[0] => 1_09122012070025_img1_L.jpg 
[1] => 1_09122012070025_img_L.jpg 
[2] => 1_09122012070025_img2_S.jpg 
[3] => 1_09122012070025_img1_S.jpg 
[4] => 1_09122012070025_img_S.jpg 
[5] => 1_09122012070025_img2_L.jpg 
)
```

I'm trying to unset the values which have S, so that I'm left with keys 0, 1, 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$array = Array(
    '1_09122012070025_img1_L.jpg',
    '1_09122012070025_img_L.jpg',
    '1_09122012070025_img2_S.jpg',
    '1_09122012070025_img1_S.jpg',
    '1_09122012070025_img_S.jpg',
    '1_09122012070025_img2_L.jpg'
);


foreach($array as $k=>$a){
    if(preg_match("/_S.jpg/",$a)){
        unset($array[$k]);
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';?>
```

Note: I matched against "_S.jpg", whereas you could just match against "S".

Comment: Thank you Samuel, that did the job perfect.